# How to use User Input in python discord.py Disord Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

### Discord.py User Input for rock, paper, scissors game.

I would like to create a **Discord Bot** that is able to **play rock, paper, scissors.** I think that the basic code of the game isn't complicated but the discord.py implementation is hard for me.
The Problem is probably this line of code `player = await bot.wait_for('message')`. I have read the discord.py docs, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.
**This is my Code:**

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['g', 'ga', 'gam'])
@commands.guild_only()
async def game(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        'Hallo, wie gehts denn so ' + ctx.message.author.mention + '? Lust auf eine Runde Schere, Stein, Papier?')

    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    ties = 0

    while True:
        await ctx.send('%s Siege, %s Niederlagen, %s Unentschieden \n' % (wins, losses, ties))
        while True:
            await ctx.send('Auf was setzt du? (s)tein, (p)apier, (sc)here oder (q)uit')  
            player = await bot.wait_for('message') 
            print(str(player))
            if player == 'q':
                return
            if player == 's' or player == 'p' or player == 'sc':
                break
            await ctx.send('Schreib s, p, sc oder q!')

        if player == 's':
            await ctx.send('Stein gegen...')
        elif player == 'p':
            await ctx.send('Papier gegen...')
        elif player == 'sc':
            await ctx.send('Schere gegen...')

        randomnum = random.randint(1, 3)
        if randomnum == 1:
            computer = 's'
            await ctx.send('Stein!')
        elif randomnum == 2:
            computer = 'p'
            await ctx.send('Papier!')
        elif randomnum == 3:
            computer = 'sc'
            await ctx.send('Schere!')

        if player == computer:
            await ctx.send('Unentschieden!')
            ties = ties + 1
        elif player == 's' and computer == 'sc':
            await ctx.send('Du gewinnst!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif player == 's' and computer == 'p':
            await ctx.send('Ich habe gewonnen!')
            losses = losses + 1
        elif player == 'p' and computer == 's':
            await ctx.send('Du gewinnst!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif player == 'p' and computer == 'sc':
            losses = losses + 1
            await ctx.send('Ich habe gewonnen!')
        elif player == 'sc' and computer == 'p':
            await ctx.send('Du gewinnst!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif player == 'sc' and computer == 's':
            await ctx.send('Ich habe gewonnen!')
            losses = losses + 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't seem to work right_ ?

Comment: Well, it did not work, because I forgot to clarify that I want to use the user input through message.content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Just change **the player variable to player.content** an it should work.

```
if player.content ==
```

**Thanks for the effort!**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a check so that it knows who the author is.

```
def check(author):
    def inner_check(message):
        return message.author == author
    return inner_check
```

Then you would pass the inner_check to wait_for by calling the outer_check with the appropriate argument:

```
playerChoice = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(context.author), timeout=30)
```

Comment: I get a NameError: name 'context' is not defined.